# Basic Flink streaming question as far as data egress is concerned

Tags: apache-flink

I am currently working on a streaming platform that accepts an unbounded stream from a source into Kafka. I am using Flink as my stream processing engine. I am able to ingest data successfully, window it on event time and do whatever I want to do in Flink. The output of this stream currently goes into a Kafka sink, which is ok for now since this data will not be streamed anywhere. This entire setup is deployed on AWS.

A external client is now interested in the data. The client wants the data in a streaming format instead of pulling the data from Kafka. We also do not want to expose our Kafka brokers to the external world. How can we achieve this? I tried pushpin proxy to "push" the data out. However, it's a pain to setup and manage.

Any idea how to approach this? I am really open to any ideas.

Thanks

Comment: What is a streaming format? Why is Kafka not suitable (except for valid security concerns)? Would Kinesis work better in this case? In general, I'd just go over the list of [connectors](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/connectors/) and pick the most suitable.

Comment: We are looking at something open source. Kinesis doesnt support protobuf and hence it's out of question. We do not want to expose Kafka brokers due to security concerns as you mentioned. Kafka connectors are extremely expensive and do not provide a push API. I am looking for something open sour e that does a server push as soon as messages are available in Kafka. Something like gRPC and HTTP2. I am not aware of how to even start other than knowing that it would fit the use case well.

Comment: Do you really want to use a Push API? If so, then your costumer probably also has some limitations/preferences. The disadvantage of Push is that it has to be highly available. I'd probably check out RabbitMQ and ActiveMQ. You could also look at [sockets](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/datastream_api.html#data-sinks) if you just want something simple and HA is not an issue.

Comment: Yes, I do need streaming since my streamed data is time sensitive. I can't afford for the clients to pull the data since it's very sensitive in terms of temporal tolerance. Think about a cable stream that you subscribe to or the Twitter stream. As a client, you get the data if you subscribe to it. Hope that helps.

Comment: Writing to sockets or files through Flink is really for debugging. I cannot extend this to Production. There is a lot of material out there that discusses Data Ingestion and Processing. However, there is literally a dearth of information around streaming the data out. It seems all technical articles end at ingestion and processing.

Comment: Twitter is actually a counter example to your requirements. The twitter API is a normal REST API, where you just repeatedly request with an HTTP client to the twitter server. Imho, this setting is what you also should aim at as you simply cannot control the consumer's server (to where you would like to push). At this point, I'd probably have a close look at [Kafka's rest proxy](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/index.html).

Comment: I do not have an option to have the consumer's pull from Kafka. Think about stock prices that are updated on an app on a periodic basic. It would be disaster if the app has to pull these from a central server. My data is very time sensitive. I am perfectly fine if the consumer misses some due to availability issues. It has to be pushed, however, since holding it with the server longer than 30 seconds will provide no benefits the client once consumed.

Comment: Virtually all apps, even highly interactive apps like games, still use the common client-server architecture, where the app pulls the data. The only common other approach I have seen so far is using Web Sockets. For your example with stock prices, afaik pulling stock prices from a server is exactly how the big stock APIs work. They usually offer half-open connections to reduce the number of requests though. But maybe some other SO user has other ideas.